# Basic probability: when two events have high probability, but their intersection has low probability

Tags: probability

Are there cases where two events have high probability (i.e. each of them has high probability) but, at the same time, the probability that they both obtain is low? If yes, could you please provide a simple, daily-life example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always a restriction to the probability of $A \cap B$:

$$1 \geq P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) \Rightarrow$$
$$P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) + P(B) -1$$
For example:

- $P(A) = 0.9$ and $P(B) = 0.9 \Rightarrow P(A \cap B) \geq 0.9+0.9-1 = 0.8$

So, the higher the probability of $A$ and $B$, the higher the lower bound for the probability of $A \cap B$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please also explain what happens when the events are more than two?

Comment: @Mijito:The case of three or more events is not so easy to handle. For example, for 3 events the relevant formula is $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$. This formula becomes even more sophisticated for more than 3 events.

Answer (score 1):

Coin flip: probability of heads is $1/2$, probability of tails is $1/2$, probability of both is $0$.